# Modular website to include all javascript in one file, or seperate files based on usage

Tags: javascript, optimization, joomla

I've created a Joomla! website, and several of the modules have their own javascript to handle various events/animations concerning that module. When I test my site for optimization, most reports say I should include fewer javascript files by combining all of the files.

Normally I wouldn't have a problem with this, however I have my concerns. Due to the nature of Joomla! (websites are modular and as such not all modules appear on all pages), wouldn't it be a waste of memory/bandwidth for the master javascript file to include javascript that isn't used/needed on that page?

Would it be better to have all the javascript files separated and added if the module is used, or have one big file that includes all javascript regardless of whether it's used or not?

Comment: You are right, it is a waste of bandwidth (and memory but that shouldn't be that much of a deal except your javascript files are really really huge). It also increases computation time if you have a lot of unneeded javascript code. You could write one master file that loads the module files per ajax call if the module is needed

Comment: P.S.: You could also inject the `<script>` tags referencing your module js files through a master file. This might be even better because of the synchronous loading style

Comment: @Markai For clarification, you mean I setup a system where if the module is present, a flag is turned on. Then in the master if said flag is checked, it goes and fetches the according script?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your site, so it's a little bit hard to tell, but i guess, that at some point in your code, you will determine which modules have to be loaded, is that right?